# Clarification on proof of Laurent development (Conway)

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, analytic-functions

I need some clarification on the proof of the Laurent series development as presented by Conway in his book Functions of One Complex Variable I, second edition, pages 107/108.

The function $f_1(z)$ is defined as
$$f_1(z) = -\frac1{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{f(w)}{w-z}dw$$
where $f(z)$ is analytic in the annulus $\mbox{ann}(a,R_1,R_2)$ and  $\gamma_1(t) = a+r_1 e^{2\pi i t}$, $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$, with $R_1 < r_1 < R_2$.

The author then states that $f_1(z)$ is analytic in
$$G=\{z:|z-a|> R_1\}.$$
But $\{\gamma_1\} \subset G$, and the integrand is not defined when $z \in \{\gamma_1\}$.

I would rather say that
$$G=\{z:|z-a|> r_1\}.$$

**Is this reasoning correct?**

Similarly (page 108) the function
$$g(z) = \begin{cases} f_1\left(a+\frac1z\right) & (z\neq 0)\\ 0 & (z= 0)\end{cases}$$
is said to be analytic in $B(0;1/R_1)$, but I would say that it is analytic in $B(0;1/r_1)$.

Comment: What is implied (I think) is that $r_1$ is chosen automatically, on a per-$z$ basis, with $R_1<|z|<r_1<R_2$. Otherwise as you say, if $r_1$ is just fixed, the integral either doesn’t make sense or is ... irrelevant, losing the perks of Cauchy’s integral formula